# Trouble with boolean result of sql record lookup

Tags: c#, sql

I've made a function that checks if a username exists already in a table, for use with account creation validation in c#. However even if i know the record already exists it still returns that the username is available. I can't understand why as when looking for an answer to this question I've followed what was recommended and it still has the same problem so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I tried removing the apostrophes, replacing the "=" with like, utilising a count(*) to check for instances but still to no avail

```
public bool isUsernameAvailable(string uName)
    {
        ConnectionString.OpenConnection();
        string Query = "SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username= '@user'";
        SqlCommand checkUsername = new SqlCommand(Query, ConnectionString.GetConnection());
        checkUsername.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", uName);
        var UserExist = checkUsername.ExecuteScalar();

        if (UserExist != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        { 
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to hard code the username, to ensure it's not the DB. For example: SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username = 'Harambe'

Comment: When its hard coded in it works correctly and recognises the record

Comment: Please see my answer for some help in improving this code. However I am glad you have an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this sql Text

```
string Query = "SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username= @user";
    SqlCommand checkUsername = new SqlCommand(Query, ConnectionString.GetConnection());
    checkUsername.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", uName);
    var result= checkUsername.ExecuteScalar();

    if (result==null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    { 
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Tried this but it just throws an error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object' 'returned null'. I tried a method similar to this previously but still had the same problem i'm experiencing now.

When i hard coded in the username i knew was there it found the record and worked correctly so I'm not really sure why it won't work

Comment: did you use Username=@user ? instead of Username='@user'

Comment: remove the single quote of @user in sql text. (WHERE Username= @user). Hopefully that will solve your problem. else check the value of uName variable

Comment: @Exceptionhandler `ExecuteScalar()` returns an object, not a int. It can be null, as seen in h3rcul35's original code. Un-quoting `@user` is the only thing you need to do to fix the code.

Comment: Using my original work and just removing the quotes around @user did the trick. Turns out I'd also made a sleep deprived mistake with the pass in when the function was called that I'd missed, passing in txtUserID.Text instead of txtUser.Text -__-

Comment: Congrats! Anyway I fixed my answer I guess

Answer (score 1):

```
public bool isUsernameAvailable(string uName)
{
    string sql = "SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username= @user";
    string connString = ConnectionString.GetConnection();

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connString))
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection))
    {
        var uNameParam = new SqlParameter("user", SqlDbType.String);
        uNameParam.Value = uName;

        command.Parameters.Add(uNameParam);
        var exists = command.ExecuteScalar();

        if (exists != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Can you try something like this? I have made a few assumptions of your code, but hopefully this will work.

Essentially, removing the quotes was all that was required, however the code below ensures the SqlConnection and SqlCommand are correctly disposed of as these implement IDisposable.

Additionally, using Parameters. Add over AddWithValue is only a small a bit of work but allows your parameter to be explicit in type.

Comment: Upvoted for the use of `using`. You may want to elaborate on what exactly you fixed, though. With the full copied code, it's easy to miss ;)

Answer (score 0):

public bool isUsernameAvailable(string uName)
    {
        ConnectionString.OpenConnection();

```
    string Query = "SELECT Username FROM Users WHERE Username=@user";

    SqlCommand checkUsername = new SqlCommand(Query, ConnectionString.GetConnection());
    checkUsername.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", uName);
    var UserExist = checkUsername.ExecuteScalar();

    if (UserExist == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    { 
        return false;
    }
}
```

Hope you need the True value when user name doesn't exists